# How to use custom urls with ember-data?

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

How is it possible to use custom urls with ember-data? For example:

```
PUT /users/:user_id/deactivate
PUT /tasks/:task_id/complete
PUT /jobs/1/hold
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to do this right now with ember-data. However, it's trivial just to fall back to ajax and use that instead. For example:

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  actions:
    deactivate: (user) ->
      # Set the user to be deactivated
      user.set('deactivated', true)

      # AJAX PUT request to deactivate the user on the server
      self = @
      $.ajax({
        url: "/users/#{user.get('id')}/deactivate"
        type: 'PUT'
      }).done(->
        # successful response. Transition somewhere else or do whatever
      ).fail (response) ->
        # something went wrong, deal with the response (response.responseJSON) and rollback any changes to the user
        user.rollback()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define fairly complex URLs from within your Ember router.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('comments', function() {
      this.route('new');
    });
    this.route('comment', { path: 'comments/:comment_id'});
  });
});
```

This gives us:

```
/posts
/posts/new
/posts/:post_id
/posts/:posts_id/comments
/posts/:posts_id/comments/new
/posts/:posts_id/comments/:comment_id
```

Ember decides whether to use GET, POST, PUT or DELETE depending on whether it is fetching from the server, persisting a new resource, updating an existing resource or deleting it.

See [here](https://github.com/ianwdunlop/ember-js-rails-blog) for a basic but functioning blog type app with posts and comments which can be persisted or [here](https://github.com/openphacts/explorer2/tree/ian_ember_1.0) for a much more complex app which fetches resources from a 3rd party server.

Comment: The router nests ember controller/views/routes but not ember-data - or is it new? Your example Block at least has no nested resources.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Your answer seems to be conflating the ember router with ember-data. Unless I'm missing something?